# How to identify what exactly is changed in a changes feed

Tags: google-drive-api

Am reading the [Manage-changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes) documentation, and tried it [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v2/drive.changes.list?includeDeleted=false&_h=4&). It shows what are the files that get changed/modified after the largestChangeId.

But from this response how do I identify what is being changed exactly! 
Say my request with largestChangeId returned one document link. Now I went back to google drive and starrted that specific document. Now when I try the same request with (largestChangeId+1) it returned a new response. How can I identify this change is caused by starring a document? Should this be only manually compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a file is changed, the corresponding entry in the Changes feed will contain a `file` property with the updated metadata:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes#resource

Instead of manually comparing properties, you should simply overwrite your local copy with the updated one.